# WebAPI v2 - JSON Serialization for OData expand causes $type to be incorrect

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, odata

I have just updated an MVC4/WebApi v1 application to MVC5 + WebAPI2..

Seems like after this upgrade the Json.Net serializer will no longer include the proper $type for requests that make use of OData $expand method. see below for an example of what i mean...

**CORRECT:**

request: http://url.com/api/Studies/277/Sites

response:

```
{
$id: "1"
$type: "LGCYDAPI.Domain.Model.StudySiteWithContacts, LGCYDAPI.Domain.Model"
Contacts: [
{
$id: "2"
$type: "LGCYDAPI.Domain.Model.ContactRelatedToSite, LGCYDAPI.Domain.Model"
ContactID: -38445
}],
SiteID: 38445
}
```

**INCORRECT**:

request: http://url.com/api/Studies/277/Sites?$expand=Contacts

response:

```
{
$id: "1"
$type: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib"
Contacts: [
{
$id: "2"
$type: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib"
ContactID: -38445
}],
SiteID: 38445}
```

Along with MVC and WebAPI assemblies, I updated JSON.NET from 5.0.6 to 6.0.3 which I thought was the problem.. however, i reverted back to v5 and it didn't fix the problem so I'm back on v6. Also updated OData nugets - my current versions are Microsoft.Data.OData=5.6.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData=5.1.2.

**JSON Serializer Settings:**

```
pConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        pConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        pConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;

        pConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $type in response payload is for the actual object to be serialized.

With $expand applied on the result, the structure of returned object is changed from `LGCYDAPI.Domain.Model.StudySiteWithContacts` to `SelectExpandWrapper`.

So you can't get your expected Sites type with $expand applied.

For `SelectExpandWrapper` structure, check this:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24select%20and%20%24expand%20support

Comment: Thank you for the information! Do you have any ideas of what alternatives or hacks I could do to make the $type read the actual type of the object? Breeze relies heavily on this...

Comment: 1. try writing a message handler to analyse the response content type and then saving it to the response. 2. try sending another almost-same request but without select and expand query options to get the actual type. 3. do not use select and query options in your request uri.